# CakePHP Blog Not Displaying Anything

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to come up to speed on CakePHP. I have used the MVC pattern before and am familiar with the idea. I have tried to follow the Blog tutorial for 2.* version of CakePHP and am having no luck.

If I navigate to `http://localhost/posts/index`, I see this:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Posts was not found on this server.

It all looks fine if I just load `http://localhost/`

The other thing I don't get is how the Controller is calling:
    `$this->Post->find(’all’));`

There is no method called `find` on the Post model. The model is completely bare:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
}
```

I don't know what to make of that. Does the framework generate a **find** method or has the write of the tutorial omitted a very important part of it?

**Edit - more details**
There is a controller in the folder app/Controller called PostsController:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array(’Html’, ’Form’);

public function index() {
    $this->set(’posts’, $this->Post->find(’all’));
}

public function view($id = null) {

    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__(’Invalid post’));
    }

    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);

    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__(’Invalid post’));
    }

    $this->set(’post’, $post);
}
```

}

There is an index view inside /app/View/Posts/

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/index.ctp -->
<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Created</th>
</tr>
<!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post[’Post’][’id’]; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post[’Post’][’title’],
            array(’controller’ => ’posts’, ’action’ => ’view’, $post[’Post’][’id’])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post[’Post’][’created’]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

The model is as set out in the original post above.

In the database, there is the following data which I used in the tutorial:

```
/* First, create our posts table: */
CREATE TABLE posts (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(50),
body TEXT,
created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
/* Then insert some posts for testing: */
INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
VALUES (’The title’, ’This is the post body.’, NOW());
INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
VALUES (’A title once again’, ’And the post body follows.’, NOW());
INSERT INTO posts (title,body,created)
VALUES (’Title strikes back’, ’This is really exciting! Not.’, NOW());
```

Comment: set debug level higher than 0 from Config/core.php and then see what http://localhost/posts/index displays

Comment: @KishorKundan The debug level was already at 2. It displays Not Found The requested URL /Posts was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I don't know what to make of that. Does the framework generate a find method, or has the write of the tutorial omitted a very important part of it?*

Yea, Framework takes care of the ORM part.. I guess you are 'super' new to this.. even I am new to cakephp... I am just 5 projects old in CakePHP, so even I am new...

Ok...

Back to your question:

You need to have a 'Post' Controller and an 'index' action.

Make sure you 'uses' Model else, you can also call it from an action like so:

```
$this->loadModel('Post');

$this->set($variable, $this->Post->find('all'));
```

and then in your views

do a :

```
<?php pr($variable) ?>
```

What is need is not the 'short term' fish but, the ability to fish yourself... The example I gave above will give you understanding of the CakePHP working.

Questions? :)

EDIT : You have issue with mod-rewrite, that's all!

Do this:

Open `app/Config/core.php`

find the line and uncomment it:

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

Delete all, .htaccess from all document root dir, app dif, webroot dir...

Solved?

Comment: It is true. I am 0 projects old. I do have a controller and model as I have been following the "create a blog" tutorial. So, my question is, why does it not work? Is the tutorial out-of-date?

Comment: I am not sure if it is outdated. Can you copy paste the 'ENTIRE' work which you have done? That would help me understand where, what is going wrong... ahh! Also, do you have demo data in the database???

Comment: I have edited the post and added the entirety of my work. There's not too much there as I did not get far into the tute, as it was failing straight away.

Comment: I had already done all that. That line is uncommented and I had deleted all the .htaccess files from those directories.

Comment: So, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I wish I knew. Identifying the problem has been the hardest part. And I'm not able to fix it, for some reason or other.

Comment: Ok.. First of all, chill out... just say.. what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25951/discussion-between-karmicdice-and-onefootswill)

Comment: Thank you for you patience. I'll produce a screen shot next time I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue sounds like a problem with mod_rewrite, please check the [URL rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) chapter from the cookbook.

*Does the framework generate a find method, or has the write of the tutorial omitted a very important part of it?*

No and no. It's plain [PHP functionality](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php), you just have to follow the inheritance hierarchy to find where the `find` method comes from: `Post` extends `AppModel` extends `Model`. And if you check the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_find) you will see that `Model` defines the `find` method your `Post` model inherits.

Comment: Yes. I get your point about the Model. Took me a while to find that file, after you mentioned it. The url rewriting is all different to my WAMP setup. And it's double dutch to me. I suspect this is the problem and I will have to burn a metric truck-load of hours figuring it out. Thanks for a nudge in the right direction.